# Help on a rational recursive relation: $T[n+1]=\frac{E[n+1](D+T[n])}{E[n+1]+D+T[n]}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve this rational recursive relation:

$$T[n+1]=\frac{E[n+1](D+T[n])}{E[n+1]+D+T[n]}$$

where $T[1]=\frac{E[1]*D}{E[1]+D}$ for constant $D>0$ and $E[n]>0$.

When $E[n]$ is replaced by a constant $E$ (independent of $n$), Wolfram Mathematica's `RSolve` (after `FullSimplify`) yields the following:

$$T[n]=\frac{2E}{1+\sqrt{1+4E/D}-\frac{2\sqrt{1+4E/D}\left(D+2E-\sqrt{D(D+2E)}\right)^n}{\left(D+2E-\sqrt{D(D+2E)}\right)^n-
\left(D+2E+\sqrt{D(D+2E)}\right)^n}}$$

I *assume* that for constant $E$ Mathematica used methods for solving [rational difference equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_difference_equation) (but I really have no knowledge of the inner workings of that software package).  It's not helpful when function $E[n+1]$ is inserted in lieu of constant $E$.

To extend the result above to function $E[n]$ I've tried writing out the first few iterations of it (using `RecurrenceTable` function in Mathematica with and without `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`), however, no pattern emerged to me (though, perhaps the community can see something -- I can try to post it to the question if that would be helpful).  I am not very familiar with recurrence relations beyond some basic facts s.t. the Master Theorem.  Is this thing even soluble? I would be very happy with a solution involving sums and products of $E[n]$.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

This arose out of my [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/bayesian-updating-using-n-noisy-observations-of-brownian-motion/23051) on the stats forum regarding Bayesian inference using noisy observations of a Brownian motion process.

Comment: When $E$ is a constant you are iterating a linear fractional transformation, or _Mobius transformation_ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), and this is easy to do in closed form by finding the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an associated matrix. When $E$ is not a constant you are instead more or less composing a family of _a priori_ unrelated matrices and I don't think you should expect anything reasonable unless you know more about $E[n]$ (for example if it were periodic you would still be fine).

Comment: I don't really know what kind of a "solution" you're even looking for. With some ingenuity you could probably write down some monstrous expression involving all of the $E[n]$s, but what good would it do you? What do you actually want to know?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan In the simplest form of my problem, I am given $D$ and a constraint on $\sum_{k=1}^nE[k]$ and am trying to minimize $T[n]$.  Looks like this might be very hard to do.

Comment: Is $n$ fixed? You might try seeing what happens in the special case that $E[k]$ has small period (since you can reduce to the case of iterating a single linear fractional transformation).

Comment: $n$ is fixed.  $E[k]$ *might* be periodic in the physical interpretation of the problem, so I'll try that.  What do you mean by "iterating a linear fractional transformation," how does one reduce the periodic case to it, and what is the associated matrix?  I am not that familiar with group theory (I think the wikipedia article you cited uses the results from it) but I am reasonably good at linear algebra.

Comment: So, some kind of method-driven explanation of how to derive a closed-form expression for $T[n]$ given a periodic $E[k]$ (which I assume means $E[k+j]=E[k]$ for some $j$) would be a very helpful start.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}$ be a **fractional linear transformation**. ($a, b, c, d$ can be taken to be complex numbers if you want but what I'm about to say works over any [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)).) The problem of studying a sequence $z_n$ of numbers satisfying
$$z_{n+1} = f(z_n)$$

reduces to the problem of iterating $f$. Perhaps surprisingly, this can be done using matrix multiplication.

**Lemma:** Let $f(z) = \frac{az + b}{cz + d}, g(z) = \frac{pz + q}{rz + s}$ be two fractional linear transformations. Then $(fg)(z) = \frac{tz + u}{vz + w}$ where
$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc} t & u \\\ v & w \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\\ c & d \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} p & q \\\ r & s \end{array} \right].$$

An alternate group-theoretic statement is that the invertible transformations of the form $\frac{az + b}{cz + d}$ form a group, the [projective general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_linear_group) $\text{PGL}_2(F)$, and there is a natural surjective homomorphism from the [general linear group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group) $\text{GL}_2(F)$ of invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices to this group. The way I stated it above doesn't require the assumption of invertibility, but if the associated matrix is not invertible then the transformation is a constant and the lemma isn't interesting anyway.

The lemma can be proven by direct computation, but a more conceptual explanation is given by a study of how $\text{GL}_2(F)$ acts on lines through the origin in $F^2$; see [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/fractional-linear-transformations-and-elliptic-curves/).

In this way the problem of iterating a fractional linear transformation reduces to the problem of taking powers of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, and to do this it suffices to find its [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form). If the associated matrix is diagonalizable then we just have to take powers of the eigenvalues and using that idea you can derive the Mathematica formula in the case where $E$ is a constant.

In the case where $E$ is periodic with small period $j$, just restrict your attention to what happens when you run the iteration $j$ times. This will be described by some specific fractional linear transformation which you can iterate by the above method until you get close to $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Mitchell "An Analytic Riccati Solution for Two-Target Discrete-Time Control", Journal of Economic Dynamics and Control 24(4), 615-622 (2000) uses an interesting trick to solve the Ricatti recurrence:
$$
w_{n + 1} = \frac{a w_n + b}{b w_n + d}
$$
Use the replacement $x_n = 1 / (1 + \eta w_n)$, select $\eta$ such that the result is a first order, linear recurrence in $x_n$. If $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are functions of $n$, so will be $\eta$, and the resulting recurrence is linear, first order and thus has a explicit solution even if the coefficients aren't constant. But unless you are as lucky as textbook writers are with all the problems that come their way, the result will be a much worse mess than just iterating the recurrence.